# using IN a where using a case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create this query for a report the '&BO_STATUS' = 'AAA' is a value that the user needs to input. When the value is AAA I want to retrieve all the BO with the status of In Progress and Confirmed. For some reason, I keep getting an error. I have been trying to do this in different ways.

```
SELECT T1.OPPORTUNITY_NO AS BO_NUMBER,
T1.SOURCE_ID_DB AS SOURCE_ID, 
T1.OPPORTUNITY_TYPE,
T1.STATE AS Status
FROM BUSINESS_OPPORTUNITY T1
WHERE
T1.STATE IN
(CASE
  WHEN '&BO_Status' = 'AAA' THEN '''In Progress','Confirmed'''
  END
)
```

Comment: And what if 

I am trying to create this query for a report the '&BO_STATUS' <> 'AAA'. What should be the output in this situation?

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a `case` EXPRESSION.  Just use regular logic:

```
WHERE '&BO_Status' = 'AAA' AND T1.STATE IN ('In Progress', 'Confirmed')
```

I imagine that you also want an "else" so the query returns something if the condition is not true.  If so, then you want:

```
WHERE ('&BO_Status' = 'AAA' AND T1.STATE IN ('In Progress', 'Confirmed')) OR
      '&BO_Status' <> 'AAA'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you are explicitly told to use `case..when` statement then you should use following:

```
WHERE case when '&BO_Status' = 'AAA' 
           Then case when T1.STATE IN ('In Progress', 'Confirmed')
                Then 1
                End
           Else 1
           End = 1
```

Or else best way of doing it is not to use `case..when` statement at all as suggested by @gordon.

```
WHERE ('&BO_Status' = 'AAA' AND T1.STATE IN ('In Progress', 'Confirmed')) OR
      '&BO_Status' <> 'AAA'
```

I am considering that when status is not `AAA` then you want everyting (no `where` condition)

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can maximize the use of `INSTR` function for this scenario. Specially when you are trying to build your string conditions.

```
SELECT T1.OPPORTUNITY_NO AS BO_NUMBER,
T1.SOURCE_ID_DB AS SOURCE_ID, 
T1.OPPORTUNITY_TYPE,
T1.STATE AS Status
FROM BUSINESS_OPPORTUNITY T1
WHERE INSTR('In Progress, Confirmed', T1.STATE, 1, 1) > 0
```